# Mirror a react component in the main and new browser window

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building an application with React and Electron (though I think answering as if it were just React will be just fine for my purposes) with a feature that is similar to PowerPoint/Google Slides Presenter View - in which a separate window is used on a second monitor for projection, but the contents are mirrored on the first screen. The version on the first screen is able to be interacted with through `onClick`s and such. The second screen may also have those events but it is not necessary - again this is just for audience viewing. The first screen will have more features on it than just the contents of the component in question.

I stumbled upon [this article](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202) which explains how to cleverly use portals to do something similar, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way since this component will be mirrored on the first screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any who might find this question in the future, the answer lied in electron's interprocess communications (ipc). When I want to set the state in the context, I run a dispatch action. When the dispatch action reaches my context, instead of calling the reducer, I first send a message to the main ipc, which then relays my action/payload to the secondary window.

```js
// context.js
function newDispatch(action) {
  ipcRenderer.send('SYNC_STATE', action);
  dispatch(action);
}

return (
  <StoreProvider value={{state, dispatch: newDispatch}}>
    {children}
  </StoreProvider>
)

// electron.js

ipcMain.on('SYNC_STATE', (_, action) => {
  secondaryWindow.webContents.send('UPDATE_STATE', action);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are managing state but you could use the window.open function to open a new tab to a specific path. Just make sure you provide that path to your router so you don't get a 404. State could get tricky, for example if you're using the context api you wont have that information available to you in the newly opened tab.

Comment: Will the component in the new window be able to share state with the one loaded in the original window? Would I be smart to use redux for this?

Comment: The state will not be shared. Each react component is a function and the scope of the variables in that function do not extend beyond the function. Redux is one solution although it seems like a lot of overhead for a presentation. You could store whatever value you want in local storage and use an effect and state to share the values. Not the most elegant solution but its probably fine in this situation.